# Wordpress Gravity Forms Dynamic Population based on Term

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to auto populate a Gravity Forms hidden field with the Term name of a Custom Post Type. The code below returns the word "Array" in the field. I need it to populate the field with the Custom Post Type category and/or child name.

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_myparameter', 'populate_post_myparameter');
function populate_post_myparameter($value){
global $post;

$myparameter = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'mytaxonomy', 'array("fields" => "names")');

return $myparameter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wp_get_post_terms will return an array even if there's just one object. If you're just looking to get the first term from that list (although possibly there are multiple entries for a post), change return $myparameter to return $myparameter[0]->name.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Nick's answer, add a little bullet-proofing, and correct a typo in your code, here's what the final code would look like:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_myparameter', 'populate_post_myparameter' );
function populate_post_myparameter( $value ) {
    global $post;

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'mytaxonomy', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

    return $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ? $terms[0]->name : '';
}
```

If you're looking for a plugin that can handle this without having to write any code, check out [Gravity Forms Populate Anything](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/).